# Mysql EF5 storegeneratedpattern identity not working

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, identity

I've read a fair amount on this issue but nothing seems to be working.

So far I have made sure that the StoreGeneratedPattern Identity is on two tables. I checked the model AND store. Both have the property set. However, when I insert into these tables, both ids are '0'.

I hope that someone familiar with these issues can take a look and tell me where I've got it wrong

Thanks

Here is the generated xml (irrelevant tables removed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
  <!-- EF Runtime content -->
  <edmx:Runtime>
    <!-- SSDL content -->
    <edmx:StorageModels>
    <Schema Namespace="rule_testModel.Store" Provider="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="5.7" Alias="Self" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns:customannotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="RateId" />
            <PropertyRef Name="RateTypeId" />
            <PropertyRef Name="PaymentPlanId" />
            <PropertyRef Name="TariffDescriptionId" />
            <PropertyRef Name="FeatureId" />
            <PropertyRef Name="FuelId" />
            <PropertyRef Name="Live" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="RateId" Type="uint" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Profile" Type="uint" />
          <Property Name="REC" Type="varchar" MaxLength="10" />
          <Property Name="PlanName" Type="varchar" MaxLength="300" />
          <Property Name="RateTypeId" Type="uint" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="PaymentPlanId" Type="uint" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Product" Type="varchar" MaxLength="45" />
          <Property Name="ContractDuration" Type="varchar" MaxLength="45" />
          <Property Name="TariffDescriptionId" Type="uint" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="TariffUnrestricted" Type="decimal" Precision="6" Scale="3" />
          <Property Name="TariffDay" Type="decimal" Precision="6" Scale="3" />
          <Property Name="TariffNight" Type="decimal" Precision="6" Scale="3" />
          <Property Name="TariffEveningWeekend" Type="decimal" Precision="6" Scale="3" />
          <Property Name="StandingChargePenceDay" Type="decimal" Precision="6" Scale="3" />
          <Property Name="StandingChargeGBPQuarter" Type="decimal" Precision="6" Scale="3" />
          <Property Name="StandingChargeGBPMonth" Type="decimal" Precision="6" Scale="3" />
          <Property Name="StandingChargeGBPYear" Type="decimal" Precision="6" Scale="3" />
          <Property Name="CapacityCharge" Type="decimal" Precision="7" Scale="3" />
          <Property Name="FeatureId" Type="uint" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="FromCon" Type="uint" />
          <Property Name="ToCon" Type="uint" />
          <Property Name="Version" Type="varchar" MaxLength="45" />
          <Property Name="PriceType" Type="varchar" MaxLength="45" />
          <Property Name="Duration" Type="uint" />
          <Property Name="SupplierId" Type="uint" />
          <Property Name="FuelId" Type="uint" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="ProposedStartDate" Type="date" />
          <Property Name="SignWindow" Type="uint" />
          <Property Name="DateAdded" Type="datetime" Precision="0" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="Live" Type="uint" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="MaxRate" Type="decimal" Precision="6" Scale="3" />
          <Property Name="MaxSc" Type="decimal" Precision="6" Scale="3" />
          <Property Name="UpStep" Type="decimal" Precision="6" Scale="3" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="conditions">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="ConditionId" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="ConditionId" Type="uint" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="ProductId" Type="uint" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Profile" Type="usmallint" />
          <Property Name="REC" Type="varchar" MaxLength="10" />
          <Property Name="RateTypeId" Type="uint" />
          <Property Name="PaymentPlanId" Type="uint" />
          <Property Name="FeatureId" Type="uint" />
          <Property Name="FromCon" Type="uint" />
          <Property Name="ToCon" Type="uint" />
          <Property Name="Duration" Type="uint" />
          <Property Name="SupplierId" Type="uint" />
          <Property Name="FuelId" Type="uint" />
          <Property Name="live" Type="bool" />
          <Property Name="TempRateId" Type="uint" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="products">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="ProductId" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="ProductId" Type="uint" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="RateId" Type="uint" />
          <Property Name="FromProductId" Type="uint" />
          <Property Name="ServiceRef" Type="uint" />
          <Property Name="UpCom" Type="decimal" Precision="6" Scale="3" />
          <Property Name="UpSC" Type="decimal" Precision="6" Scale="3" />
          <Property Name="FixedCom" Type="decimal" Precision="8" Scale="3" />
          <Property Name="Live" Type="bool" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="BrokerId" Type="uint" />
          <Property Name="MaxRate" Type="decimal" Precision="6" Scale="3" />
          <Property Name="MaxSC" Type="decimal" Precision="6" Scale="3" />
          <Property Name="Step" Type="decimal" Precision="6" Scale="3" />
          <Property Name="Fits" Type="decimal" Precision="6" Scale="3" />
          <Property Name="Disc" Type="decimal" Precision="6" Scale="3" />
          <Property Name="UpliftTypeId" Type="uint" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="SupplierId" Type="uint" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="FromCon" Type="uint" />
          <Property Name="ToCon" Type="uint" />
        </EntityType>
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="word_id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="word_id" Type="int" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="word_context" Type="varchar" MaxLength="45" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="word_word" Type="varchar" MaxLength="255" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityContainer Name="rule_testModelStoreContainer">
          <EntitySet Name="conditions" EntityType="Self.conditions" Schema="rule_test" store:Type="Tables" />
          <EntitySet Name="products" EntityType="Self.products" Schema="rule_test" store:Type="Tables" />
        </EntityContainer>
      </Schema></edmx:StorageModels>
    <!-- CSDL content -->
    <edmx:ConceptualModels>
      <Schema Namespace="rule_testModel" Alias="Self" annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns:customannotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
        <EntityContainer Name="eBroker2Entities" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
          <EntitySet Name="products" EntityType="rule_testModel.product" />
          <EntitySet Name="conditions" EntityType="rule_testModel.condition" />
        </EntityContainer>
        <EntityType Name="product">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="ProductId" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="ProductId" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="RateId" Type="Int32" />
          <Property Name="FromProductId" Type="Int32" />
          <Property Name="ServiceRef" Type="Int32" />
          <Property Name="UpCom" Type="Decimal" />
          <Property Name="UpSC" Type="Decimal" />
          <Property Name="FixedCom" Type="Decimal" />
          <Property Name="Live" Type="Boolean" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="BrokerId" Type="Int32" />
          <Property Name="MaxRate" Type="Decimal" />
          <Property Name="MaxSC" Type="Decimal" />
          <Property Name="Step" Type="Decimal" />
          <Property Name="Fits" Type="Decimal" />
          <Property Name="Disc" Type="Decimal" />
          <Property Name="UpliftTypeId" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="SupplierId" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="FromCon" Type="Int32" />
          <Property Name="ToCon" Type="Int32" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="condition">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="ConditionId" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="ConditionId" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="ProductId" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Profile" Type="Int32" />
          <Property Name="REC" Type="String" MaxLength="10" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
          <Property Name="RateTypeId" Type="Int32" />
          <Property Name="PaymentPlanId" Type="Int32" />
          <Property Name="FeatureId" Type="Int32" />
          <Property Name="FromCon" Type="Int32" />
          <Property Name="ToCon" Type="Int32" />
          <Property Name="Duration" Type="Int32" />
          <Property Name="SupplierId" Type="Int32" />
          <Property Name="FuelId" Type="Int32" />
          <Property Name="live" Type="Boolean" />
          <Property Name="TempRateId" Type="Int32" />
        </EntityType>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:ConceptualModels>
    <!-- C-S mapping content -->
    <edmx:Mappings>
      <Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs">
        <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="rule_testModelStoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="eBroker2Entities">
          <EntitySetMapping Name="products">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="rule_testModel.product">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="products">
                <ScalarProperty Name="ToCon" ColumnName="ToCon" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="FromCon" ColumnName="FromCon" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="SupplierId" ColumnName="SupplierId" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="UpliftTypeId" ColumnName="UpliftTypeId" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Disc" ColumnName="Disc" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Fits" ColumnName="Fits" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Step" ColumnName="Step" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="MaxSC" ColumnName="MaxSC" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="MaxRate" ColumnName="MaxRate" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="BrokerId" ColumnName="BrokerId" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Live" ColumnName="Live" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="FixedCom" ColumnName="FixedCom" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="UpSC" ColumnName="UpSC" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="UpCom" ColumnName="UpCom" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="ServiceRef" ColumnName="ServiceRef" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="FromProductId" ColumnName="FromProductId" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="RateId" ColumnName="RateId" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="ProductId" ColumnName="ProductId" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
          <EntitySetMapping Name="conditions">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="rule_testModel.condition">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="conditions">
                <ScalarProperty Name="TempRateId" ColumnName="TempRateId" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="live" ColumnName="live" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="FuelId" ColumnName="FuelId" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="SupplierId" ColumnName="SupplierId" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Duration" ColumnName="Duration" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="ToCon" ColumnName="ToCon" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="FromCon" ColumnName="FromCon" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="FeatureId" ColumnName="FeatureId" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="PaymentPlanId" ColumnName="PaymentPlanId" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="RateTypeId" ColumnName="RateTypeId" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="REC" ColumnName="REC" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Profile" ColumnName="Profile" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="ProductId" ColumnName="ProductId" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="ConditionId" ColumnName="ConditionId" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
        </EntityContainerMapping>
      </Mapping>
    </edmx:Mappings>
  </edmx:Runtime>
  <!-- EF Designer content (DO NOT EDIT MANUALLY BELOW HERE) -->
  <Designer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
    <Connection>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="MetadataArtifactProcessing" Value="EmbedInOutputAssembly" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </Connection>
    <Options>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="ValidateOnBuild" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="EnablePluralization" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="IncludeForeignKeysInModel" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="UseLegacyProvider" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="CodeGenerationStrategy" Value="None" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </Options>
    <!-- Diagram content (shape and connector positions) -->
    <Diagrams></Diagrams>
  </Designer>
</edmx:Edmx></Mapping>
    </edmx:Mappings>
  </edmx:Runtime>
  <!-- EF Designer content (DO NOT EDIT MANUALLY BELOW HERE) -->
  <Designer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
    <Connection>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="MetadataArtifactProcessing" Value="EmbedInOutputAssembly" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </Connection>
    <Options>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="ValidateOnBuild" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="EnablePluralization" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="IncludeForeignKeysInModel" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="UseLegacyProvider" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="CodeGenerationStrategy" Value="None" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </Options>
    <!-- Diagram content (shape and connector positions) -->
    <Diagrams></Diagrams>
  </Designer>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doh!

So it turns out it didn't like the db types I was using such as unsigned